# Lower Running Headers in Koma Classes

Tags: header-footer, margins, koma-script

In the scrbook class, my running headers are too high. I've looked at page 44 of the manual ("Calculating the Page Layout with typearea") but while this addresses two line headers, it does not explain how to drop headers that are too high. This is the class option I am using:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11.5pt,paper=6in:9in,BCOR=7.5mm,headlines=1.25]{scrbook}
```

MWE:

```
\documentclass[fontsize=11.5pt,paper=6in:9in,BCOR=7.5mm,headlines=2]{scrbook}
\usepackage[%
  left=.375mm,
  right=.375mm,
  top=.375mm,
  bottom=.375mm,
 ]{geometry}
 \KOMAoptions{DIV=calc}
 \recalctypearea
\usepackage[automark]{scrlayer-scrpage}
  \pagestyle{headings}
\automark[section]{chapter}

\usepackage{blindtext}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Chapter 1}
\blindtext[3]
\section{Section 1}

\blindtext[3]

\section{Section 2}

\blindtext[3]

\end{document}
```

Comment: By "too high" I mean extending into the bleed.

Comment: .375mm, specifying lengths in .001 mm???  but koma has extensive built in ways to specify the layout, including `paper=6in:9in,BCOR=7.5mm,headlines=2` it isn't clear that loading `geometry` on top  will work well

Comment: I tried to find a native way to specify the margin settings--set by the printer--in Koma, but the manual said to use the \geometry package. So I did. If there's a "native" way to do this in Koma, happy to do so. Also, .375mm was supplied by the printer.

Comment: specifying margins of less than half a millimetre seems optimistic, but then using  `\recalctypearea` which will re-adjust the margins so the text block is a multiple of baselineskip, which may therefore change them by 3 or 4 mm means you are quite likely to end up with spurious outcome.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle So your suggestion is...

Comment: your example ends with the warning `LaTeX Font Warning: Size substitutions with differences
(Font)              up to 1.02895pt have occurred.` so you are tolerating  .4mm difference in font size on _every line_ but specify margins of less than .4mm specfied to 3dp on the page. First I'd double check with the printer those margins which seem weird why have  page size in inches and margins in mm? but simply commenting out `%\KOMAoptions{DIV=calc}
 %\recalctypearea`   will let `geometry` have control and you get the specfied margin (ie no margin at all, essentially)

Comment: [margins as specified to geometry](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x83EV.png)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147018/discussion-between-user26732-and-david-carlisle).

Comment: Do you really want the margins to be as small as technically feasible? It seems to me that your printer probably specified a _minimum_ margin (i.e. "Here's where I can't print."). Since any reasonable text margin (like the KOMA defaults) is much larger than that, there really is no need to do anything about it, at least not for the printer's sake. What is the _typesetting result_ you want?

Comment: Is adding bleed to the paper size the solution, e.g. `6.25in:9.25in` ?

Comment: Shouldn't `\topskip` work? But it doesn't: `\setlength{\topskip}{3mm}` does nothing

Comment: @schtandard: at this point, I would like to know how to set fixed, as opposed to calculated, margins in the Koma classes without using the `geometry` package.

Comment: @user26732 Well, if you want to set the layout page layout manually, use the `geometry` package (or the TeX registers directly) and do _not_ use KOMA Script's layout functions. Have a look at the [`layout`](https://ctan.org/pkg/layout) package if you are unsure on the meaning of the lengths.

Answer (score 1):

Inserting this code drops the running headers as required:

```
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\renewcommand*{\chaptermarkformat}{}
\ohead{\vspace*{-1.5cm}\headmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
```

The key line is the `\ohead` command. If you omit the last line you lose page numbers.

Comment: I can't take credit for this answer, so I won't mark it.